# Scala Slick join query

Tags: database, scala, slick

I'm performing a join in slick like so:

```
 val query = for { 
          o <- Orders if o.id === order_id
          p <- o.part_key
        } yield (o,p)
        query.list
```

which creates the following error message:

```
value list is not a member of org.scalaquery.ql.Query[(code.model.Orders.type, code.model.Parts.type)]
```

If I just return an Order or Part the query works fine:

```
 val query = for { 
          o <- Orders if o.id === order_id
          p <- o.part_key
        } yield o
        query.list
```

How can I return a list of tuple from a slick join query? Why am I getting the error message above?

Comment: How have you defined Orders? And what are you importing?

Comment: Are you using scalaquery or slick? There's no `org.scalaquery` package in slick anymore... maybe there's a wrong `import`?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way for you to return a tuple in the query is to use:

```
val list = (for { 
      o <- Orders if o.id === order_id
      p <- o.part_key
    } yield o ~ p).list
```